# How to use PDFNet instance across the ruby app

Tags: ruby, pdfnet

I have to initialize the PDFNet library once in my app. I did it in my `app.rb` which is run first

```
# app.rb
require 'PDFNetC/Lib/PDFNetRuby'
include PDFNetRuby
PDFNet.Initialize(ENV['PDFTRON_LICENSE_KEY'])
```

Later in my controller I need to convert pdf to xod for which I will require the initialized PDFNet instance

```
# SomeController.rb
out_file_path = "#{ENV['TEMP_DIR']}/#{Time.now.to_i}.xod"
::PDFNetRuby::Convert.ToXod(in_file_path, out_file_path)
File.open(out_file_path, 'rb')
```

Will the above method get the license registerd instance of PDFNet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PDFNet.Initialize is a process wide call, so if both code snippets are in the same process, both will be in licensed mode.

Comment: Is PDFNet a singleton? Why isn't that using an instance to do the conversion?

Comment: PDFNet is fully compatible with multi-threading, but some API calls are synchronized and affect all threads. PDFNet.Initialize is such a call. If you are having a particular issue, perhaps you should create a new SO question detailing what exactly that is. Or edit this one, as it is unclear what issue (if any) you are having.